# Replicating a Python workflow for pre-processing of an image for Tensorflow in a Javascript environment

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, pyodide

In my python code, I'm pre-processing an image and feeding it to a model for predictions.:

```
path = "/Users/iamreddy831/Desktop/ArchitecturalStyle_ML/FinalTests/testimage3.jpg"
styles = ["Baroque", "NeoClassical", "Gothic", "Modern", "Victorian"]
def read_image(file_path):
    print("[INFO] loading and preprocessing image…") 
    image = load_img(file_path, target_size=(300, 300)) 
    image = img_to_array(image) 
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image /= 255. 
    return image
def test_single_image(path):
    styles = ["Baroque", "NeoClassical", "Gothic", "Modern", "Victorian"]
    images = read_image(path)
    time.sleep(.5)
    bt_prediction = vgg19.predict(images) 
    tf.shape(bt_prediction)
    preds = model.predict(bt_prediction)
    for idx, styles, x in zip(range(0,7), styles, preds[0]):
        print("ID: {}, Label: {} {}%".format(idx, styles, round(x*100,2) ))
        print("Final Decision:")
    time.sleep(.5)
    for x in range(3):
        print("."*(x+1))
    time.sleep(.2)
    class_predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(bt_prediction), axis=-1)
    class_dictionary = generator_top.class_indices 
    inv_map = {v: k for k, v in class_dictionary.items()} 
    print("ID: {}, Label: {}".format(class_predicted[0],  inv_map[class_predicted[0]])) 
    return load_img(path)
```

How can I run this python code on a webpage to preprocess images from the page for input? I looked into Tensorflow.js and recreating the workflow, but I think because it relies on applications.vgg19 (which exists in Tensorflow but not Tensorflow.js) I have to create a python environment to do the same/similar thing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){

  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const batchedImage = languagePluginLoader.then(function () {
      console.log(pyodide.runPython(`
          import sys
          sys.version
          import tensorflow as tf
          from tensorflow import keras
          from tensorflow.keras import applications
          tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(
            image, data_format=None
      `));
    });
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(batchedImage);
  result.print();
run();
</script>
```

Am I using Pyodide correctly in this case? I keep getting syntax errors when trying to execute this live. Or is there an easier way to approach this problem? The reshaping is rather complex, a [-1, 9, 9, 512] array that is dependent on convolutional layers.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach looks correct (not sure why you are getting syntax errors), however a major limitation is that you will only be able to import [packages with C extensions that have been built for pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/tree/master/packages). Tensorflow is not in the list, and it's unlikely that it will be added soon given that it's fairly complex, and has a long list of dependencies.

So you won't be able to import tensorflow or keras in pyodide. If you all you need is to apply [tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L104), you can take that function and adapt it to be pure numpy which should work then if you define it in pyodide directly.

About syntax errors, maybe try to progressively remove code lines until it's working to identify the issue.